# Generate a jagged array for Algorithm::Cluster using push?

Tags: arrays, perl, jagged-arrays

The perl package Algorithm::Cluster takes as one input a jagged array.  There
is an example in that package 14_kmedoids.t which contains this:

```
my $matrix   =  [
    [],
    [ 3.4],
    [ 4.3, 10.1],
    [ 3.7, 11.5,  1.1],
    [ 1.7,  4.1,  3.4,  3.4],
    [10.1, 20.5,  2.5,  2.7,  9.8],
    [ 2.5,  3.7,  3.1,  3.6,  1.1, 10.1],
    [ 3.4,  2.2,  8.8,  8.7,  3.3, 16.6,  2.7],
    [ 2.1,  7.7,  2.7,  1.9,  1.8,  5.7,  3.4,  5.2],
    [ 1.6,  1.8,  9.2,  8.7,  3.4, 16.8,  4.2,  1.3,  5.0],
    [ 2.7,  3.7,  5.5,  5.5,  1.9, 11.5,  2.0,  1.7,  2.1,  3.1],
    [10.0, 19.3,  1.0,  3.7,  9.1,  1.2,  9.3, 15.7,  6.3, 16.0, 11.5]
];
my ($clusters, $error, $found);
my %params1 = (
        nclusters =>         4,
        distances =>   $matrix,
        npass     =>     10000,
($clusters, $error, $found) = Algorithm::Cluster::kmedoids(%params1);
```

The static declaration of a jagged array in that test works.  However, when I try to make a similar jagged array dynamically, using push like this:

```
   my @sq_dm;
   # code omitted that fills sq_dm with data
   my @matrix;
   for($i=0; $i<$rowcount;++$i){
      my @row=();
      for($j=0; $j<=$i;++$j){
         push @row, $sq_dm[$i][$j];
      }
      push @matrix, @row;
   }
```

The resulting matrix does not work.  It fails with:

```
Row 0 is not an array at ./kcluster_my_script.pl line 119.
```

where line 119 is this one:

```
($clusters, $error, $found) = Algorithm::Cluster::kmedoids(%params1);
```

The static matrix appears to start with an empty row, which might be the problem, but
how might one push an empty row?  Does that empty row serve some special purpose?

Note also that in the dynamic one it is @matrix, whereas in the static one it is $matrix.  I could not make the push build the jagged array unless @matrix was used.

This is perl 5.8.8 on RHEL 5.11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to take a reference of your array, to build an AoA:

```
push @matrix, \@row;
```

For more info complex structures, check out [perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

It may be too cluttered, but your initialization code can be compressed to the following:

```
my @matrix = map [ @{ $sq_dm[$_] }[ 0 .. $_ ] ], ( 0 .. $rowcount - 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Can you explain the purpose of the empty array in the first line of the static declaration?  If it is omitted the kmedoids function complains and exits.  Is there some rule that an array or arrays must start with an empty array, or is that just a requirement for this particular package?

Comment: That's just a requirement of that particular module.